# Do variables in closures have their own scope?

Tags: python

I have two questions about this code:

```
def a_funcs():
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 0

    a_local = A()
    def set_a(a):
        a_local.a = a
    def get_a():
        return a_local.a
    return set_a, get_a

set_a, get_a = a_funcs()
print(get_a())
set_a(17)
print(get_a())
```

Does `a_local` keep existing after `a_funcs` have been returned? Is it still in the scope of `a_funcs`? Can it happen that the garbage collector deletes `a_local`?

Where is `a_local` stored technically? On the stack or on the heap?

Comment: Does this answer your second question? [CPython - Internally, what is stored on the stack and heap?](/q/2353552/4518341) TL;DR: It's an implementation detail, but in CPython, the heap.

Comment: Yes. For CPython that is the answer to my question.

Comment: If it'd help your understanding, you could plug the code into [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and skip to the last step to see what references what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `a_local` is scoped in `a_func`. The variable is no longer aaccessible by this name after returning from the function. When you enter the function again, you will get a new one.

But the (mutable) value where it points to cannot be deleted by the garbage collector. There are still references to it, hidden in the function `set_a` and `get_a`. These functions are still accessible after returning from the  function `a_func`.

The pointer to the piece of storage where the value of `a_local` is located is on the stack. But the storage for the value must be on heap because it keeps living after returning from `a_func`.

Comment: Can I then assume that everything in Python is stored on the heap and the stack only contains pointers to the actual data? Because in the moment when local_a is created, Python does not know yet that it is going to appear in a closure.

Comment: @habrewning I am not quite sure how it has been implemented. In many cases the interpreter would be able to prove that a value cannot be accessed after returning from the function. It is a matter of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Not disagreeeing with @donat, but expanding upon what he wrote.  Try:

```
set_a1, get_a1 = a_funcs()
set_a2, get_a2 = a_funcs()

set_a1(10)
set_a2(20)
print(get_a1())
print(get_a2())
```

You will see that each call to `a_funcs()` creates a new variable, and that the functions returned by `a_funcs()` refer to the variable that was just created.

Comment: Yes, that was clear. And I also tested this. But I was wondering how it can be that local variables keep existing any more. And that was answered.